# "AFTER" not suport using ucannacess ALTER TABLE?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

Why "AFTER" not support in ucannacess ALTER TABLE?

I want to add column in position to exist column table; using database `.accdb`

`sql = "ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN newColumnName VARCHAR(50) AFTER columnNameExist";`

***Example***

`sql = "ALTER TABLE car ADD COLUMN information VARCHAR(50) AFTER name ";`

***Exception***

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token : AFTER

Comment: @Shashanth thanks for editing the question better. Until now I haven't found the answer to the problem above

Comment: I don't use the MS-Access database in my projects. I use RDBMS like MySQL. I went through the official doc for MS-Access [ALTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql#syntax) command. But, I didn't find any keyword `AFTER` which we can use with `ALTER` command. So, I don't think MS-Access supports `AFTER` command. Hence, the error is valid in your case.

Comment: @ScaryWombat sir this question is not related to MySQL instead it's related to MS-Access. You marked it with the wrong dupe target.

Comment: @Shashanth Thank you for bringing this to my attention.  I had to scour really hard to find that this was related to ms-access.  Maybe a tag would have been better.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think this has to do with mysql, because the syntax used is the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ADD COLUMN instead of this use only "ADD" in place of "ADD COLUMN"
Example : ALTER TABLE  `members` ADD  `date_of_registration` date NULL AFTER  `date_of_birth`;
Hope this works.

Comment: thank you for responding. but this still shows the error "type not found or user lacks privilege: AFTER"

Comment: Can you please try by putting the table_name in double quotes .